# Using a 2TB WD passport USB drive and WinXP

Tags: windows-xp

Opinions/Advice/Solution needed.

I ordered a 2TB WD "Passport" backup drive for a computer running WinXP.

I must have still been under anesthesia thinking,

1) XP would recognize such a large hard drive,

AND . . .

2) that this 2TB passport would NOT come GPT formatted which XP also does not recognize.

At this point upgrading the PC to Win7 or Win 10 is not an option.

I need to backup all current data on the XP's 500GB drive as well as an already full WD500GB "MY Book" external hard drive.

I'm thinking I have to remove the GPT type format (if XP is going to recognize it) and most likely that will mean 4 separate logical 500GB NTFS partitions or no?

Can I leave this passport intact at 2TB and reformat it to NTFS or at least separate logical 1TB partitioned NTFS drives?

Any input will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Windows XP can recognise a 2TB drive (which is about the maximum size of a disk which does not require GPT).  Simply repartition it as a single 2TB disk using with MBR, and reformat using NTFS (or whatever format works best for your needs)

Comment: I found a link to https://www.paragon-software.com/technologies/components/gpt-loader/winXP.html which appears to be some kind of driver to support GPT on Windows XP if you want to shell out US$20 for the privilege as an alternative solution.  (I've not tried it)

Comment: thanks davidgo, i'm trying a linux progie called gpart to mbr and will attempt to reformat to ntfs

Comment: Ok.  If that doesn't do it, just use "dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX bs=512 count=1" to overwrite the initial MBR, unplug the disk and plug it in again, then use fdisk to partition it.  (I'm sure gparted will work fine, I've just not used it much)

Comment: Got a 2TB USB on my box and XP sees it just fine. Wasn't GPT, when I got it, but Gparted Live sees it, and has partitioned it for me just fine. Best to let XP do the formatting though.

Comment: thanks gypsy i used diskpart to clean drive, and then partitioned it as NTFS and WinXP recognized it fine.